Shopify: How can I create dynamic prices for products?
I've integrated a custom product configurator via a custom Shopify App on the product page. The configurator has a lot of options that'll affect the final price.
I've already figured out how to add the product to the cart with the Storefront API but it only adds the base variant and its price.
My question is now: Since I can't know in advance which variants I'll have (there are just to many options), is there any way I can modify the price of the product in the cart/checkout via the Admin or Storefront APIs?
Or can I create something like dynamic variants?
